# Erro de mapeamento duplicado: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingExceptionn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou utilizando Hibernate 5 e estou tendo o seguinte problema:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: duplicate import: br.edu.unifeob.entidades.apuracao.Avaliacao refers to both br.edu.unifeob.entidades.apuracao.Avaliacao and br.edu.unifeob.entidades.apuracao.Serie (try using auto-import="false")
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addImport(Configuration.java:2892)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.bindEntity(EntityBinder.java:401)
```

Já tentei anotar minhas entidades dessa forma mas não adiantou:

```
@Entity(name="br.edu.unifeob.entidades.apuracao.Avaliacao")
@Table(name="Avaliacao")
public class Avaliacao {
...
}

@Entity(name="br.edu.unifeob.entidades.base.Avaliacao")
@Table(name="Avaliacao")
public class Avaliacao{
...
}
```

As duas classes estão em unidades de persistência diferentes. Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Já pesquisei e a única forma que encontrei de resolver o problema é utilizar o name da anotação @Entity pra diferenciar as entidades.

Comment: Qual o código completo destas 2 entidades "Avaliacao"?

Comment: De onde vem este br.edu.unifeob.entidades.apuracao.Serie ?

Comment: Você não pode ter 2 classes "representando" a mesma tabela

Comment: @PedroLaini, nunca tentei, mas acho que é possível sim.

Comment: como está a classe java que configura ou o persistence.xml?

Comment: Se as duas classes estão em unidades de persistência diferentes, você poderia mapeá-las pra uma tabela de mesmo nome. A questão é, como você está injetando ou criando os entityManagers na tua aplicação?

Answer (score 0):

Uma dessas entidades será utilizada apenas como leitura? 
Se sim, você pode incluir o **@Immutable** nesta entidade:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Avaliacao")
public class Avaliacao {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Avaliacao")
@Immutable
public class Avaliacao {
...
}
```

Conforme exemplo aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007676/how-to-map-two-hibernate-entities-on-the-same-database-table